# How to make order by rand() not take effect with pages?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code that printing rows randomly from the table `combbined_attack` and show's 10 result per page.

```
    if (!isset($_GET['page']))  {
        $_GET['page'] = 10;
    }
    if(empty($_GET['page']))    {
        $PageNumber = 1;
    } else  {
        $PageNumber = abs($_GET['page']);
    }
    $First_limit = $PerPage * $PageNumber - $PerPage;
    $Limit = $First_limit;

$get_av = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `combined_attack` WHERE (army_1=0 || army_2=0) && start=0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $Limit,$PerPage");
```

Everything works good, but when I'm moving between the pages the query is randomize the results again and makes the pages irrelevant.

any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Don't do that.  No, seriously.  What is it you're attempting to accomplish?  Most of the time, you want a specific order - that's the only way to make the results stable.  Otherwise, you have to have some sort of query-run-id that you upload to the db that gives you a stable order.  Why do you think you want a "random" order?

Comment: I need it to be randomly, but also with pages. I don't need it to be same sorting every-time. I want to make it randomly only when someone is at page 1. but keep the same sorting if he moved trought the pages.

Comment: And I'm saying you almost never want that, because it leads to really strange behavior.  For example, if you're trying to figure out who "won" a fight, the outcome may depend on statement run - what happens if both sides request information at the same time? You either need to cache the ordering somehow (either by storing something db-side, or storing all rows in php), or choose a stable ordering.  Note that `ORDER BY RAND()` can't use indices, so it will be slow.

Comment: thank you, I'll keep that in mind. but I still want to figure out way of doing it. I'm trying to print 'fighting rooms', it's now affacting anything but the position of the room in the list users see.

Comment: @OfirH You could fetch the entire result set and storing it / caching it. So instead of sending the pagination start/limit to sql you do it in your loop. Not really something that's usually recommended (to fetch all results), but I'm not sure how else you could get what you want with order by rand..

Comment: You can random the results after you select them with `shuffle()` and then you dont need this `RAND()`

Comment: Side note - you're potentially open to SQL Injection.  You should be using parameterized queries.